# How to reference an existing organization folder, or other resources, in Terraform (For GCP)

Tags: google-cloud-platform, terraform, terraform-provider-gcp

I'm pretty new to Terraform, my apologies if this question has an obvious answer I'm missing.

I am trying to create a terraform configuration file for an existing organization. I am able to provision everything I have in the `main.tf` outlined bellow except for the `Shared` folder that already exists within this organization.

Related github issues :

- [The folder operation violates display name uniqueness within the parent.](https://github.com/terraform-google-modules/terraform-example-foundation/issues/33)
- [Generic error message when folder rename matches existing folder](https://github.com/hashicorp/terraform-provider-google/issues/1903)

Here are the steps I followed:

1. Manually create a `Shared` folder within the organization administration UI.
2. Manually create a **Terraform admin project** `<redacted-project-name>` at the root of the `Shared` folder.
3. Manually create a service account named `terraform@<redacted-project-name>` from the **terraform admin project**
4. Create, download and securely store a key for the `terraform@<redacted-project-name>` service account.
5. Enable APIs : `cloudresourcemanager.googleapis.com`, `cloudbilling.googleapis.com`, `iam.googleapis.com`, `serviceusage.googleapis.com` within the **terraform admin project**
6. Set permissions of the service account to **role/owner**, **roles/resourcemanager.organizationAdmin**, **roles/resourcemanager.folderAdmin** and **roles/resourcemanager.projectCreator**.
7. Create the `main.tf`

```
terraform {
  required_providers {
    google = {
      source  = "hashicorp/google"
      version = "3.85.0"
    }
  }
}
provider "google" {
  credentials = file(var.credentials_file)
  region      = var.region
  zone        = var.zone
}
data "google_organization" "org" {
  organization = var.organization.id
}
resource "google_folder" "shared" {
  display_name = "Shared"
  parent       = data.google_organization.org.name
}

resource "google_folder" "ddm" {
  display_name = "Data and Digital Marketing"
  parent       = data.google_organization.org.name
}

resource "google_folder" "dtl" {
  display_name = "DTL"
  parent       = google_folder.ddm.name
}
```

The error I receive :

```
Error: Error creating folder 'Shared' in 'organizations/<redacted-org-id>': Error waiting for creating folder: Error code 9, message: Folder reservation failed for parent [organizations/<redacted-org-id>], folder [] due to constraint: The folder operation violates display name uniqueness within the parent.
```

How do I **include** existing resources within the terraform config file?

- For (organization) folders (such as the example above)
- For the billing account
- For projects, i.e. Am I supposed to declare or import the **terraform admin project** within the `main.tf`?
- For service accounts, how to handle existing keys and permissions of the account that is running the `terraform apply`
- For existing policies and enabling APIs

Comment: I used `lifecycle` -> `ignore_changes` in a similar use-case, but not sure if that's the proper solution: https://www.terraform.io/docs/configuration-0-11/resources.html#ignore_changes

Comment: Apparently it is possible to reference the existing resources by identifying them, adding them to the relevant template e.g. `main.tf` and performing a `terraform import` on them.
For my case with the folder it is `terraform import google_folder.shared folders/<redacted_folder_id>`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order to include already-existing resources within the terraform template, use the `import` statement.

## For Folders

In the [Terraform documentation for google_folder](https://registry.terraform.io/providers/hashicorp/google/latest/docs/resources/google_folder) :

```
# Both syntaxes are valid
$ terraform import google_folder.department1 1234567
$ terraform import google_folder.department1 folders/1234567
```

So for the example above,

1. Fetch the **folder id** using `gcloud alpha resource-manager folders list --organization=<redacted_org_id>` providing the organization id.
2. Save the folder id somewhere, and if not already done, declare the folder as a resource within the `main.tf`

   ```
   resource "google_folder" "shared" {
   display_name = "Shared"
   parent       = data.google_organization.org.name
   }
   ```
3. Run the command : `terraform import google_folder.shared folders/<redacted_folder_id>`. You should get an output like `google_folder.shared: Import prepared!`
4. Make sure your infrastructure is updated via `terraform plan`.

   ```
   No changes. Your infrastructure matches the configuration.

   Terraform has compared your real infrastructure against your configuration 
   and found no differences, so no changes are needed.
   ```

Comment: Be sure you executed "terraform refresh" and "terraform plan" before the import, otherwise, a lot of errors might occur.